oauth2-server npm: Where should I generate the client id and secret
I am working on creating an oauth2 server using the oauth2-server npm package.  I am trying to implement the Access Token request approach as outlined here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.3.2.  I created the model and the endpoint functions for authorize, authenticate, test, token as per the oauth2-server npm docs.  The server runs but when I hit the token endpoint, the client id and secret are expected.

How do I generate a client id and secret?  This is for an internal single page app in-house.  Not currently integrating with facebook, google, etc.

In the access token doc, this is how the request should look:
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w

where the client id and secret are in the Authorization header.

For generation, what format do the client id and secret need to be in?

